# Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6

Just upgraded to node 4.1.2 and using Mongorito (which uses ES6) to access Mongo and I'm getting this:

Model file:

```
var Mongorito = require('mongorito');
var Model = Mongorito.Model;
var config = require('../config/config');
Mongorito.connect(config.mongo.url);

class Listing extends Model {}

module.exports = Listing;
```

And I'm including it:

```
var Listing = require('../models/listing');
var listing = yield Listing.where('cacheKey', key).findOne();
```

```
TypeError: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'
      at Listing.Model (/node_modules/mongorito/lib/mongorito.js:140:15)
      at new Listing (/models/listing.js:7:14)
      at Query.find (/node_modules/mongorito/lib/query.js:355:21)
      at [object Generator].next (native)
      at onFulfilled (/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)
      at run (/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:89:39)
      at /node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:100:28
      at flush (/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/core-js/modules/$.microtask.js:17:13)
      at doNTCallback0 (node.js:408:9)
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:337:13)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is because Babel's transpiled ES6 classes cannot be used to extend a real ES6 class. If you want to use `mongorito`, you would have to blacklist Babel's `es6.classes` transform so that your `Listing` class was also a native ES6 class.

Comment: Thanks. Completely forgot I was using Babel.

Comment: is that the only work around? Is there any documentation on why this is?

Comment: Related (@loganfsmyth has answered this before):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577683/babel-error-class-constructor-foo-cannot-be-invoked-without-new

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if you use [es2015](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015) preset on the library side allows the user to extend classes defined on them.

**`.babelrc`**:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

I didn't tested on `mongorito`, but I was having the same problem extending a 3rd party class and using this preset solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Transpiled classes are causing the problem.
If you are using the env preset, you can exclude the *classes* plugin like this:

```
  presets: [
    ["env", { exclude: ["transform-es2015-classes"] }]
  ]
```