# Babel error: Class constructor Foo cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using babel to transpile.

I have `class BaseComponent` which is extended by `class Logger`.

When I run `new Logger()` in the browser, I am getting this error

Class constructor BaseComponent cannot be invoked without 'new'

the code that throws this is:

```
var Logger = function (_BaseComponent) {
  _inherits(Logger, _BaseComponent);

  function Logger() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Logger);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(Logger).call(this, "n")); //throws here
  }
```

Comment: Is this the output of babel, or code that you've written? (If this is output, show the code you wrote.)

Comment: What is `BaseComponent`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth is just a ES6 class

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Due to the way ES6 classes work, you cannot extend a native class with a transpiled class. If your platform supports native classes, my recommendation would be, instead of using the preset `es2015`, use `es2015-node5`, assuming you're on Node 5. That will cause Babel to skip compiling of classes so that your code uses native classes, and native classes can extend other native classes.

Comment: oh, that is really limiting, I'm moving to composition anyway!

Comment: @loganfsmyth -  I am getting similar error. I have a typescript file and it's extending a javascript file (with associated typings file).  Is this an issue because typescript can't extend transpiled javascript file and it can only extend another typescript file?

Comment: I just had the same issue as well, trying to extend a TypeScript class in CoffeeScript (which I'm having transpiled by Babel because for some reason Node *still* doesn't support ES6 imports).

My solution was to configure `babel-preset-env` to target the latest Node version (see http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/), this transpiles only the `import` statements and leaves the classes alone.

Comment: What is the fix for using Node 12?

Answer (score 12):

Another solution is to include `{ exclude: ["transform-es2015-classes"] }` in `.babelrc`

```
presets: [
   ["env", { exclude: ["transform-es2015-classes"] }]
]
```

UPDATE: In the latest version of "env" preset plugin names have changed (e.g. it's now "transform-classes").  Use the "debug" option to inspect which plugins are included.

Comment: You mean to `include` transformation of classes into functions?

Comment: Perfect solution.

Comment: This is the solution but it should be `include` instead of `exclude`.

Comment: Thanks it works! `include: ['transform-classes'],`