# class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new

Tags: angular, typescript, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to use a 3rd party typescript library(antlr - https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4ts) in my angular 2 project created using angular-cli. It's failing with this error
**class constructor MyLexer cannot be invoked without 'new**. If you look at below code snippet , it's failing while making call to super();.Also  Lexer.js is sitting in node_modules of antlr library.

I am not using babel in my project but I found this other stackoverflow post which has similar error as mine [Babel error: Class constructor Foo cannot be invoked without 'new'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577683/babel-error-class-constructor-foo-cannot-be-invoked-without-new). It says that due to the way ES6 classes work, you cannot extend a native class with a transpiled class. Is it somehow related to my issue as well? Please guide.

**Code snippet**

```
let inputStream = new ANTLRInputStream("sometext");
      let lexer = new MyLexer(inputStream); // it fails here
      let tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
      let parser = new MyParser(tokenStream);
```

**MyLexer.ts** (Generated code)

```
    export class MyLexer extends Lexer {
        constructor(input: CharStream) {
                super(input); // it fails here. 
                this._interp = new LexerATNSimulator(MyLexer._ATN, this);
            }    
        // more code
     }
```

**Lexer.js** (sitting in node_modules)

```
class Lexer extends Recognizer_1.Recognizer {
    constructor(input) {
        super();
//more code
```

Comment: Code similar to this works fine on my system. So it must be some odd configuration issue on your end. Could you please post ideally a GitHub repo or Gist? Failing that, at least your package.json and tsconfig.json? (I realize this is from 2017 but hey nobody answered yet)